# When we call a function recursively,does it involve a single call stack or one for each invocation of the function?

Tags: c, recursion, callstack

When in the following code  I invoke the function `fact()` from `main()`,will this invocation of `fact()` involve a single call stack for `fact()` or since `fact()` is recursive in nature,it will involve a separate call stack for each recursive invocation of `fact()` that would follow? I am new to recursion and clueless about it.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fact(int);

int main(void)
{
 int a=8;
 printf("The factorial of 8 is %d",fact(a));
}

int fact(int a)
{ 
    if(a==1)
    return 1;
    return a*fact(a-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one callstack (unless we deal with threads). It goes from `main` to whatever the currently last call is. Each call to any function will form a "stackframe" on the stack, which contains the argument(s) to the function, the return address where it goes back to on return and any local variables inside the function.

As mentioned in some answers, there are cases where the compiler will eliminate the recursion as part of it's optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with all warnings and debugging info (i.e. with `gcc -Wall -g` on Linux) then use a debugger (`gdb` on Linux) to step (`step` command to `gdb`) and show the backtrace (`bt`).

There is one single call stack (per thread), but a call stack contains several call frames.

When the machine calls a function, a new stack frame is installed (pushed) on the call stack. When that function returns, the current (topmost) call frame is removed (popped).

Read about [call stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) on Wikipedia. Read also about [tail calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: I use CodeBlocks in Win XP and compile through GUI.

Comment: So learn how to compile with debugging info and how to start the debugger.

Comment: please state your answer in simple words.You mean one single call stack for **each** invocation of the function,ie 8 times?And what are call frames?

Comment: Please follow the links I gave to you.

Comment: The words in blue (`call stacks` and `tail calls` in the last sentence) are web links, click on them.

Comment: Do I have to to read the entire contents of those two pages for an answer to my question?All I asked is if it takes a single stack or a stack for each invocation.That's what I need at the moment.

Comment: Yes, you have to read the wikipages if you want to understand. Or read some good book like [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), and yes, **learning take time**.

Comment: `A stack frame is a part of the call stack, and a new stack frame is created every time a subroutine is called`---Thank, I got my answer.That's all I needed to know for the moment.

Comment: Here's the link I found.It's a lot more helpful and answers the question straightaway http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/explanation-of-recursion/

Answer (score 0):

Each call to a function preserves the memory space on the stack, so it does not matter if it's a recursive call or not, always have a different space on the stack, to avoid overlaps other state between calls to the other functions.

Comment: Some compilers are able of tail-call optimizations.... (but the code posted by the OP is not tail-recursive, so they won't make it a tail-call)